# Why do I get Android errors on Qt projects loading?

Tags: android, qt, mingw, project, qmake

I do not use any Android features of Qt, my only purpose is to program some little softwares for Windows with minGW and QMake, no other project configurations is relevant for my needs. I'm simply curious if I missed a part, it does not affect the fonctionnality.

> Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable
>   to point to your Android NDK

And a bunch of other errors like that. Its my 4th clean install of 4 different version of Qt bundle, (now I carefully unselect everything except minGW32 and it still showing up!) God's sake why?

Did I missed a part on How to use Qt? Do I need extra-steps to remove it manually on a project creation?

Comment: What "Kit" did you select in Qt Creator?

Comment: Desktop_Qt_5_9_9_MinGW_32bit. The only one I ever selected (Not to mention I'm beginner with Qt)

Comment: @drescherjm If I do what the message told me, it would be to use android kits, wich I don't want to use. Not for now, maybe someday

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code for **Windows**: just setting up your project with default setting (without Android/IOS setting).

If you want to code for **Android**: The problem was that the file wasn't the correct NDK file. Make sure you get the correct NDK from the website. Other than that it is pretty easy just unzip it and that directory is the root directory.

Comment: Exactly! For Windows, I choose Qt widget or Qt Consol, then at the Kits selection window I uncheck "select all" and re-check MinGW (the "select all" come back..) and this is all I see I could do. I would like to send my screenshots to my reply but its my first time here I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand, I can't remove "Android options" from Qt as it is pre-installed for all platforms.

Then yes, even if I don't use it, I must install Android NDK. Then continue to unselect the kit. Then these Error messages will disapear.

Comment: That's very weird, which Creator version is that? Certainly you don't need to install Android NDK if you are not using an Android kit

Comment: Is that so? :o 
Qt Creator 4.11.0

Comment: are these errors actually preventing your from building for MinGW? Here on macOS I see similar warnings now when building for macOS desktop, due to some problem in my Android setup. Despite what the "ERROR:" suggests, it's just a warning and doesn't prevent me from building for macOS.

Comment: No, It does build well. I'm not getting any issues with my project even when I had those errors.